# Backup sqltabledata and structure into an output file

Tags: c#

Hi currently i am developing an windows form application to backup table data and table structure to an output file and i am using 3rd party dll to back up it and i have 3 radiobuttons in which user selects 
1. To backup only table data
2. To back up only table structure.
3. To backup both table data and structure.

With that 3rd party dll i managed to do 2nd and 3rd points . To achive first one i am doing 3rd bit first and finally in my output file there will be both tabledata and table structure and if i want only table data i am trying to delete lines till schem bit and leave the data part and for that iam using following code :

```
   StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder(); 
        using (StreamReader tsr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            do
            {
                string textLine = tsr.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
                {
                    if (textLine.StartsWith("INSERT INTO"))
                    {

                        newText.Append(textLine + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            }
            while (tsr.Peek() != -1); 
            tsr.Close();
        }
        System.IO.TextWriter w = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath);


        w.Write(newText.ToString());
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
```

If i am doing above coding i am missing GO between INSERT INTO statements as i want GO between each insert into statement . Please help and let me know is there anything worng with my approach

Comment: I'm just curious — what database engine you use that it can't back up table and data on its own? Or is there any reason to re-implement backup?

Comment: Yes actually as per my requirement i must backup only few tables in the selcted database and selected server

Comment: actually, MS SQL Server allows you to do that

Comment: @laroslav Kovtunenko has given you the answer to your real question. I just want to point out GO is not SQL, it's a directive, to whatever is executing the sql. Steer well clear of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible approach: just don't write the program, use SQL Server features.

https://serverfault.com/questions/147638/dump-microsoft-sql-server-database-to-an-sql-script

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-script-data-in-sql-server-2011.aspx

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/11/16/sql-server-2005-generate-script-with-data-from-database-database-publishing-wizard/